# change ImageView gravity in RelativeLayout in code

Tags: android, imageview

I have:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:onClick="LogoAnimate"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

I need to change from:

```
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_centerVertical = "true"
```

to:

```
android: layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android: layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
```

*How can I implement this in the code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with `LayoutParams`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.FALSE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.FALSE);

ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
img1.setLayoutParams(params):
```

Comment: Actually all 4 `params.addRule` code lines are wrong. The right syntax is `public void  addRule (int verb, int anchor)` but this is usable to align to some object with ID set as anchor. For this snippet only left param is enough. Besides there are no `RelativeLayout.TRUE` and `RelativeLayout.FALSE` constans exists.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
   ImageView image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
  image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT));
```

Comment: This is Wrong - `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` has no such constructor. Available constructors are: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs)`
`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(int w, int h)`
`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source)`
`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source)`